# Equations in a plane parallel to two given vectors

Tags: geometry

> Let $\Pi$ be the plane through the point $P$ with position vector $\mathbf{p} = (1,2,3)$ parallel to both $\mathbf{a} = (3,0,2)$ and $\mathbf{b} = (1,-2,1)$. Decide which one of the vector equations below is true for every point $V$ (with position vector $\mathbf{v}$) in the plane $\Pi$: here, $\lambda$ and $\mu$ denote real parameters.
>
> $(A) ~ \mathbf{v} \times \mathbf{p} = \lambda \mathbf{a}+\mu\mathbf{b}; ~(B) ~\mathbf{v} = \mathbf{p}+\mu (\mathbf{a}+\mathbf{b});~ (C) ~ \mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{p} = \mathbf{p}\cdot(\mathbf{a}+\mathbf{b});~(D)~ (\mathbf{v} - \mathbf{p})\cdot (\mathbf{a} \times \mathbf{b}) = 0~(E) ~ \mathbf{v} = \lambda \mathbf{p}+\mu (\mathbf{a}+\mathbf{b}); ~ (F) ~ \text{none of these}.$

Let $(x,y,z)$ be the normal vector of $\Pi$. Since $\Pi$ is parallel to $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$, we have $(x,y,z) \cdot \mathbf{a} = 0$ and $(x,y,z) \cdot \mathbf{b} = 0$ so $(x,y,z) \cdot (3,0,2) = 0$ and $(x,y,z) \cdot (1,-2,1) = 0$ and solving this gives the normal vector $(x,y,z) = (4,-1,-6).$ Using this and since the point $P$ is in the plane, we have $(4,-1,-6)\cdot (x-1,y-2,z-3) = 0 \implies 4x-y-6z+16 = 0. $ So that's the equation of $\Pi$.

I feel I'm overcomplicating this since I have gotten nowhere with this. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You determined the plane, but you have to judge the proposals.

Re A: The RHS defines a plane parallel to $\Pi$, the LHS gives a vector orthogonal to both $p$ and the candidate $v$. This seems not to work, but we need a counter example. We note that $v=0$ would satisfy A, while $\Pi$ has the distance $\lvert d \rvert$ from the origin with $d = n \cdot p$ and the plane unit normal $n = (a \times b) / \lVert a \times b \rVert$. We have
$$
a \times b 
= (3,0,2) \times (1,-2,1)
= (4,-1,-6)
$$
and
$$
(a \times b) \cdot p = (4,-2,-6) \cdot (1,2,3) = 4-4-18=-18
$$
so $d \ne 0$ and $\Pi$ does not contain the origin.

Re B: This is the equation of a line, so it lacks one dimension to describe $\Pi$.

Re C: We test for $v = p$, which has to be in $\Pi$, we have
$$
a + b = (4,-2,3) \\
(a+b) \cdot p = (4,-2,3)\cdot (1,2,3) = 4 - 4 + 9 = 9 \\
p \cdot p = (1,2,3) \cdot (1,2,3) = 1 + 4 + 9 = 14
$$
thus $p$ does not satisfy C, and C does not describe $\Pi$.

Re D: This equation works, it uses the normal $n = a \times b$.

Re E: This is a plane but it should be different from $\Pi$. It contains the origin, so it is not $\Pi$.

Re F: This is not true, as D was fine.

Comment: Many thanks! $\space {}$